# make new environment

Tags: errors, environments

I found a Code in the internet that makes an environment and I can't solve the error. Please help me.

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{TikZ}
\usepackage{xcolor,mdframed}
%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ftjfyg}
\section{sdg}
\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newrobustcmd\ExampleText{%
An \textit{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation has the form
%\begin{align}
%L[v ] = f,
%\end{align}
where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is the dependent
variable, and $f$ is a given non−zero function of the independent
variables alone.
}

\newcounter{theo}[section]
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
{\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr−\ht\strutbox\relax,}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
\ExampleText
\end{theo}
\begin{theo}
\ExampleText
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the error? :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Please, bear in mind, that it makes more sense, to define new commands and environments in the preamble, than rather in the document.  So move the code up before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. The package is named `tikz`, not `TikZ`.
2. This is a more subtle one.  The minus sign in

   ```
   frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr−\ht\strutbox\relax
   ```

   is not a regular hyphen but [MINUS SIGN (U+2212)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm).  As a minus sign in TeX dimensions only the regular hyphen is allowed, i.e.

   ```
   frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
   ```

   (You might notice that the hyphen `-` is a bit shorter than `−`)

However, I think you should use the builtin support for theorems of `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\mdtheorem
  [linecolor=blue!20,linewidth=2pt,
   frametitlebackgroundcolor=blue!20,
   skipabove=1ex,skipbelow=1ex]
  {theo}
  {Theorem}

\begin{document}

\def\ExampleText{%
  An \emph{inhomogeneous linear} differential equation has the form
  \begin{align}
    L[v] = f,
  \end{align}
  where $L$ is a linear differential operator, $v$ is the dependent
  variable, and $f$ is a given non−zero function of the independent
  variables alone.%
}

\begin{theo}[Inhomogeneous Linear]
  \ExampleText
\end{theo}

\begin{theo}
  \ExampleText
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I chang the color of the background of this environment box?

Comment: @FarshadGholami Add `backgroundcolor=<color>` to the options of `\mdtheorem`.  See the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) for more info.